# Add a link to only pseudo element with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to add a link to a pseudo element, but not the parent element. I'm brand new to javascript, and after doing a lot of research I've been able to add a link to both the parent and pseudo elements, but I don't want the parent to be linked. It unfortunately will have to be a pseudo element because I don't have the option of adding another div to the html.

I have a fiddle which is kind of a mash of a few different fiddles I've found. Please let me know if I'm on the right track, or if this is even possible. And let me know if there is any additional information I can provide.

One more thing to note, is that the parent div will have child divs as a menu, which is why I'd prefer the parent not be clickable. But after testing (at least in the fiddle as it is now) the child links are still be clickable and correct, and these will still need to be clickable as well.

Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/mqb9juhn/1/

```
<div id="example">
<div class="example-child">
Test <a href="http://www.yahoo.com/">Test 2</a>
</div>
</div>
```

```
#example {
  position: relative;
}

#example::before {
  content: "click here"!important;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ffff00;
  top: 0;
}
```

```
var UID = {
    _current: 0,
    getNew: function(){
        this._current++;
        return this._current;
    }
};

HTMLElement.prototype.pseudoStyle = function(element,prop,value){
    var _this = this;
    var _sheetId = "pseudoStyles";
    var _head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var _sheet = document.getElementById(_sheetId) || document.createElement('style');
    _sheet.id = _sheetId;
    var className = "pseudoStyle" + UID.getNew();
    
    _this.className +=  " "+className; 
    
    _sheet.innerHTML += "\n."+className+":"+element+"{"+prop+":"+value+"}";
    _head.appendChild(_sheet);
    return this;
};

$(document).ready(function(){ $("#example").on('click', function(){
     window.location = "http://www.google.com/";});
});
var div = document.getElementById("example");
div.pseudoStyle("before","color","#ff0000");
```

Comment: You can't manipulate pseudo elements using JS, because they are not part of the DOM

Comment: _“It unfortunately will have to be a pseudo element because I don't have the option of adding another div to the html.”_ - if you can use JavaScript, then you can add whatever actual elements you want to the DOM.

Comment: I've used the mouse coordinates to detect whether the mouse is on a pseudo-element or on the actual element.

Comment: Can't you even access `.innerHTML` of parent element? (so you would use `parent.innerHTML = parent.innerHTML + value`; value would be a string with <a> and lhref of your choice)